# Cannot get a text value from a error formula cell

Tags: java, excel-formula, apache-poi

Hii i'm getting an error

> Cannot get a text value from a error formula cell

while fetching the value of a cell which has a formula.  i am using Apache poi 3.17

Below is my code:-

```
 public ArrayList<String> excelread(int sheetnum, int rownum, int lastcell) throws IOException{  // to read the expected values from the excel sheet 

            ArrayList<String>expected= new ArrayList <String>();

                File src= new File(filepath);               //Writing in excel 
                FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(src);
                XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
                XSSFSheet sh=wb.getSheetAt(sheetnum);
                XSSFRow row=sh.getRow(rownum);
                XSSFFormulaEvaluator evaluator= wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

            for (int currentcell=1;currentcell<=lastcell;currentcell +=2){
                    XSSFCell cell= row.getCell(currentcell);
                    evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell);
                    String expectedresult = sh.getRow(rownum).getCell(currentcell).getStringCellValue(); // getting the value from a particular row and cell 
                    expected.add(expectedresult);  
                }
             wb.close();
            return expected;
}
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear, isn't it? The formula in `cell` evaluates to an error. I would recommend using `DataFormatter` for getting the cell content, as shown in [Getting the cell contents](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Getting+the+cell+contents). Else you needs checking the `CellType` always before getting the content.

Answer (score -3):

Use ExcelDataReader in C#

string savepath =HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Modules/Test/Excel/excel.xls");

var excelData = new ExcelDataReaderCaller(savepath );

public class ExcelDataReaderCaller
    {
        string _path;
        public ExcelDataReaderCaller(string path)
        {
            _path = path;
        }

```
    public IExcelDataReader getExcelReader()
    {
        FileStream stream = File.Open(_path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        IExcelDataReader reader = null;
        try
        {
            if (_path.EndsWith(".xls"))
            {
                reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
            }
            if (_path.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
            {
                reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
            }
            return reader;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<DataRow> getData()
    {
        var reader = this.getExcelReader();
        var excelSheet = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
        {
            ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
            {
                UseHeaderRow = true
            }
        });

        var sheetsName = from DataTable sheets in excelSheet.Tables select sheets.TableName;
        string sheetName = sheetsName.Take(1).FirstOrDefault().ToString();

        var workSheet = reader.AsDataSet().Tables[sheetName];

        if (workSheet.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            var rows = from DataRow a in workSheet.Rows select a;

            reader.Close();
            return rows;
        }
        else
        {
            reader.Close();
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

To Get Value

var Data = excelData.getData();

```
        if (Data != null && Data.Any())
        {
            foreach (var row in Data)
            {
                var  objData = new DataInfo()
                {
                    FirstName = row[0].ToString(),
                    SurName = row[1].ToString()
                };

                ObjDataList.Add(objData);
            }
            Data= null;
            return ObjDataList;
        }
```

// ObjDataList = Make New List

Comment: Can you please state why you are thinking that `C#` code could be the answer to a question about `Java`?